# ssh-askpass on Mac OS 10.9/Mavericks broken?

Tags: macos, ssh

On Mac OS 10.7 and 10.8 (separate computers) I've been using a `ssh-askpass` script to let me verify the use of SSH keys:

https://github.com/TimZehta/mac-ssh-confirm

However, this does not seem to work on Mavericks/10.9?

Plain SSH keys works fine:

```
box ~$ ssh-add -D
All identities removed.
box ~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa)
box ~$ ssh remotehost
remotehost ~$
^D
```

But with `-c`, it no longer works..

```
box ~$ ssh-add -D
All identities removed.
box ~$ ssh-add -c ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa)
The user must confirm each use of the key
box ~$ ssh remotehost
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Password for user@remotehost:
```

`/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass` is owned by root and has `+x`. It does not even get executed it seems (added simple `touch a-logfile` line, never called).

Any ideas or hints on how to debug further?

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved! When in doubt, read the source...

ssh-agent won't call ssh-askpass unless the DISPLAY env variable is set.
Most likely it has been working on earlier installations, since I had X11 installed. Not on this box (yet).

Workaround:

Patch the ssh-agent LaunchAgents file:

```
--- org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist.orig    2014-05-22 09:55:53.000000000 +0200
+++ /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist    2014-05-22 09:56:31.000000000 +0200
@@ -9,6 +9,11 @@
        <string>/usr/bin/ssh-agent</string>
        <string>-l</string>
    </array>
+   <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
+   <dict>
+       <key>DISPLAY</key>
+       <string>:0</string>
+   </dict>
    <key>ServiceIPC</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Sockets</key>
```

Then restart your computer.

Or reload it by force, however SSH_AUTH_SOCK will be invalid in all new terminal sessions:

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist                        
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(launchctl getenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK)                 
ssh-add -c ....
```

Problem solved!

Note: the ssh-agent plist file will probably be overwritten on upgrade... Might be cleaner ways to ensure DISPLAY is set.

Comment: Finally, an explanation as to the real issue. Indeed, mine must have stopped working after installing X11. Thanks for the info! Should have RTFM myself...

Comment: Thanks! on OSX 10.9.5, trying to run an automated vagrant process via phpstorm, the process would fail when 'Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...'

Failed with error "no askpass" 

The above tweak seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 10.9 and @jstrom's solution didn't work for me. For me, the `DISPLAY` variable was already being set. The problem was a missing `ssh-askpass` program:

```
[q@haywire/0 ~] ls /usr/libexec/ssh-askpass
ls: /usr/libexec/ssh-askpass: No such file or directory
echo $SSH_ASKPASS
(no output)
```

You can fix this by using a custom `ssh-askpass` program such as [jcs's](https://github.com/jcs/openssh-mac/blob/master/cocoa-ssh-askpass) (requires CocoaDialog) or [markcarver's](https://github.com/markcarver/mac-ssh-askpass).

I prefer to copy this program to `~/bin/ssh-askpass`. This requires specifying this location in the `SSH_ASKPASS` variable; add this to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
export SSH_ASKPASS=~/bin/ssh-askpass
```

You may also need to make this variable available in launchd context:

```
launchctl setenv SSH_ASKPASS $SSH_ASKPASS
```

Before it works, you'll need to restart or at least kill and restart the `ssh-agent`:

```
killall ssh-agent
ssh-add -c -t 1h
```

Comment: As my initial post stated, ssh-askpass from https://github.com/TimZehta/mac-ssh-confirm was used.

Comment: Ah, I see. I assumed you were using one that comes bundled in OS X, which I mysteriously didn't have. =)

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't any askpass bundled.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the various replacements for ssh-askpass, I put this code in my `~/.bashrc` to ensure the launchd environment is always properly set every time I start a shell. Placing this in `~/.bash_profile` did not yield consistent results and this code executes very quickly so running it every time a shell starts isn't an issue.

I set `DISPLAY` here to avoid having to add it as a key in `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/org.openbsd.ssh-agent.plist`, plus it avoids having to edit stock plists. I check that display is already set because I don't want to set it blindly if it's already set by something else, say Xquartz.

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == darwin* ]]; then
    env_ssh_askpass="`/bin/launchctl getenv SSH_ASKPASS`"
    if [ "x${env_ssh_askpass}" != "x/opt/libexec/ssh-askpass" ]; then
            /bin/launchctl setenv SSH_ASKPASS /opt/libexec/ssh-askpass
            env_display="`/bin/launchctl getenv DISPLAY`"
            if [ "x${env_display}" == "x" ]; then
                    /bin/launchctl setenv DISPLAY bogon
            fi
            /usr/bin/killall -9 ssh-agent 2>&1 >/dev/null
    fi
fi
```